# Json4sJacksonSupport for Akka Http

Tags: json, scala, serialization, akka-http

Spray gives out of the box support for Json4sJackson by

```
 import spray.httpx.Json4sJacksonSupport
```

which I didn't find for the Akka HTTP, Moving my project from spray framework to Akka-HTTP requires my custom JSON serializer which was written using `Json4sJacksonSupport` by spray .
How can I convert the serializer to make it compatible with akka, all I find are some of the JSON unmarshaller written by https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json 
which has support for `Json4s` and `Jackson` and others but not `Json4sJackson`.

Comment: Did you try adding `libraryDependencies += "de.heikoseeberger" %% "akka-http-json4s" % "1.16.1"`?

Comment: @mfirry the dependency you are talking about is  for json4s support , I need to add the custom json serializer using Json4sJackson support

Comment: Here's a little example of what I'm using https://gist.github.com/mfirry/1b9311c9d0f0c0a274bc794434af9688

Comment: or https://gist.github.com/mfirry/1b9311c9d0f0c0a274bc794434af9688#file-myjsonservice-scala